# expdp where clause errors

Tags: oracle, where-clause, clause, expdp

I'm attempting to do an export dump based on a query clause. The table holds 2.37bil rows and i need to dump a subset of those. Here is my parfile

```
DIRECTORY=EXPSOURCE
DUMPFILE=obs_fact_%u.dmp
PARALLEL=4
TABLES=schema1.observation_fact
QUERY='schema1.observation_fact:"WHERE concept_cd < ''ICD10CM:N93.0'';"'
```

This is producing the following error

```
ORA-31693: Table data object "SCHEMA1"."OBSERVATION_FACT" failed to load/unload and is being skipped due to error:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

I tired wrapping the concept_cd code in quotations rather than double ' but receiving the same error. I've been researching for awhile now with no advancement.

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QUERY` clause is wrong because:

- you don't enclose it into single quotes
- you don't have to use two single quotes around strings
- you don't terminate the `WHERE` clause with a semi-colon

which means that something like this should work:

```
QUERY=schema1.observation_fact:"WHERE concept_cd < 'ICD10CM:N93.0'"
```

---

Here's an example based on Scott's schema: parameter file (which looks similar to yours; I can't use the `PARALLEL` option as I'm on 11gXE):

```
directory=ext_dir
dumpfile=obs_fact_%u.dmp

tables=dept
query=dept:"where dname < 'VANCOUVER:N93.0'"
```

Execution:

```
c:\Temp>expdp scott/tiger@xe  parfile=parfile_01.txt

Export: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on ╚et Srp 26 22:15:41 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Starting "SCOTT"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01":  scott/********@xe parfile=parfile_01.txt
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 64 KB
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TRIGGER
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
. . exported "SCOTT"."DEPT"                              5.929 KB       4 rows
Master table "SCOTT"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for SCOTT.SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01 is:
  C:\TEMP\OBS_FACT_01.DMP
Job "SCOTT"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully completed at 22:15:44


c:\Temp>
```